# XCode can't find j2objc jre_emul library

Tags: xcode, j2objc

I import **j2objc** to my project, but I still get error like `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Test` (`public class Test` in java source). I found something about wrong linking static library to project (`libjre_emul.a`). I found possible official solution add to **Other Linker Flags** flag `"-l jre_emul"`.

Problem is I get error `ld: library not found for -l jre_emul` what does it mean? How can I fix this?

I tried extended command:

```
"-l jre_emul -ObjC -force_load ${PROJECT_DIR}/lib/libjre_emul.a"
```

Error library not found still remains. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a spelling error in your `other linker flags`. Try to use something like:

```
-l"jre_emul"
```

Comment: It's quite confusing sometimes... Use letter 'l' instead of pipe symbol '|' in other linker flag

Answer (score 0):

The -force_load flag is no longer necessary. The issue is that the linker can't find the library because the path to it is not defined in your project (it's probably not in ${PROJECT_DIR}/lib, unless you explicitly put it there). The [Update the Build Settings wiki](https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Xcode-Build-Rules#update-the-build-settings) section describes how to add the J2ObjC distribution path to your project's Library Search Paths build setting.